# VB.NET How to Get Path of Opened Folder?

Tags: vb.net, path, get, arguments, directory

I'm trying to implement a VB.NET script which shows the full path of the ***opened folder*** when clicking right click inside it (not selecting its name),

I attached a screenshot to explain myself.
[image]

Now, I already know how to do it when selecting either a ***file*** or a ***folder***,,

I found questions here about getting all active/opened windows, but that's not my target. I just want the full path of a specific folder where I right clicked.

So for example, If I click the option "***sPaste***", I should get a messagebox with the text "***C:\test***"

```
Sub Main(ByVal args As String())

Dim path as a String = ""

            For Each arg As String In args
                path = path & " " & arg & ""
            Next arg

  Messagebox.show(path)

End Sub
```

Sending the ***argument %1*** to my app as it for the filename or the folder would not work here because there is nothing selected.

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure you need this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If there is nothing selected, there is nothing to send to your app as args

Comment: @Plutonix , so I understand that there is no way to get the path of an opened folder with clicking on the white space?